# p4 diff does not show newly added files

Tags: perforce

I need some help.
How do I get diff using p4 diff so that my patch contains
information about newly added files too ?

```
p4 add foo.cc
p4 diff > my.patch
```

my.patch should contain foo.cc

Answer (score -2):

p4 diff compares files on your client with what's in the depot on the server.  If you haven't submitted your changelist containing the new file to add, then the file isn't on the server, so there's nothing to compare.

To use p4 diff...

1. Mark the file for add, as above ('p4 add //myworkspace/myfile')
2. Submit the changelist to add the file to the P4 server ('p4 submit')
3. Checkout the new file locally with 'p4 edit //myworkspace/myfile'
4. run 'p4 diff //myworkspace/myfile'

If you haven't edited the file since step 3, it shouldn't show any differences.  If you edit the file after checking it out (and save your changes locally), step 4 will show diffs.